# Intel VT enable but not found in xenserver

Tags: virtualization, xen, ibm, intel, intel-vt-x

I have an IBM 206M with this CPU --> Intel Presler Pentium D 950 Socket LGA 775 P4D 3.4 Ghz 800Mhz FSB 4M Cache EM64T. It has Intel Virtualisation tecnology. But when i want to install xen server, the installer tell me that i have no virtualisation technology ??

Do i need to have Intel VT-x techlology also in my CPU to make it work ?

Answer (score 1):

Likely you need to enable VT in the BIOS.

Comment: I can't find that option in the bios. Is it because the does not support that option. I expect to find that option in the CPU section in the bios ...

Comment: Is it listed as Vanderpool?

Comment: I didn't see that option either. But i'll check that this evening.

Comment: When i use the tool provided by intel called Intel processor identification utility it says that the Intel virtual technooogy was enable like this --> http://virtualization.sysprobs.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/intelutility.png.